# Can canceling a NSURLConnection lead to problems?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

Before my view loads I call:

```
[theConnection cancel]; //assume theConnection is an NSURLConnection
```

I then proceed and make my proper NSURLConnection.

Will calling cancel before a connection is even made cause any problems?

Comment: I don't see why it was necessary to downvote this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the NSURLConnection documentation makes it clear that cancel is possible and that the delegate will receive no further messages once it is called. Also that the delegate is released on cancel.